# How to make button that change form background Image C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make some app and I want the button that when I click i can browse images from file on my computer and then change that image to the form background

I have tried many of code but still can't find one

```
private void ChangeBackgroundImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //how can I open the browse dialog and choose image file
            //and after that, change that image to form backgroundimage?
        }
```

*Im new to this

Comment: _I have tried many of code but still can't find one_ You should have shown your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a button. You will have to use [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to get the file path, after that you can configure the button click by lambda

```
this.BackgroundImageChanged += new EventHandler((object sender1, EventArgs e1) =>
        {
            //if the background image has changed
        });
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "images|*.png;*.jpeg;*.jpg";
        // You can Use "|All Files|*.*" and other to filter the files.
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //if path picked
        {
            button1.Click += new EventHandler((object sender1, EventArgs e1) =>
            {
                string PathFile = dialog.FileName;
                this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(PathFile);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //if path not picked
        }
```